# Upload a File in ASP.net MVC2 using C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

I have seen a great many tutorials about how to do file uploads. So far none of them really line up at all with what I am trying to do. Which is using the MVC method to, without using anything third party, upload an image to the web server and verify the size of the image. Almost all of the tutorials I have seen show how to do an upload in web forms. If anyone could point me to a tutorial that is MVC based or produce a short example that would be fantastic.

Comment: What should the user use to upload the image if not a web form?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use controller method with HttpPostedFileBase parameter? 
Like

```
 <form>
       <input type="file" name="fileUploader" />
       <input type="submit" />
  ...
```

and

```
public ActionResult AcceptFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileUploader) 
{
    .... 
}
```